# C++ Header File Needs a Reference to a Function of Another Class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, header-files

I have incorporated polymorphism with a single subclass for now. Two of these functions, as seen in the following code, Draw() and SetValue(int,int,int) are causing linker errors.

```
 #include "Header.h"

 class Object{
int tag;
 public:
void SetValues(int,int,int);
void Draw();
int getTag(){
    return tag;
}
 };
class Square: public Object{
int red;
int green;
int blue;
void Draw();
void SetValues(int red2,int green2, int blue2){
red=red2;
green=green2;
blue=blue2;
}
};
void Square::Draw(){
 // Draws a square with a gradient color at coordinates 0, 10
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  {
glColor3f(red, green, blue);
glVertex2i(1, 11);
glColor3f(red * .8, green * .8, blue * .8);
glVertex2i(-1, 11);
glColor3f(red * .5, green * .5, blue * .5);
glVertex2i(-1, 9);
glColor3f(red * .8, green * .8, blue * .8);
glVertex2i(1, 9);
  }
  glEnd();
}
```

The errors

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Object::SetValues(int,int,int)" (?SetValues@Object@@QEAAXHHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl State::DrawAll(void)" (?DrawAll@State@@QEAAXXZ)    C:\Users\Asher\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Procedural Terrain\Procedural Terrain\State.obj    Procedural Terrain
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Object::Draw(void)" (?Draw@Object@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl State::DrawAll(void)" (?DrawAll@State@@QEAAXXZ)    C:\Users\Asher\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Procedural Terrain\Procedural Terrain\State.obj    Procedural Terrain
```

In a larger class, which does no inherit Object's functions, uses DrawAll() with a Draw() call in it.
The cpp file and the two respective header files are as follows.

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "Object.h" 
float rotate_z=0;
class State{
private:
std::vector<Object> storage;
public:
State();
State Interpolate(State, State, double);
void Integrate(State,double, const double);
void DrawAll();
void AddObject(Object);
void RemoveObject(int);
};
State::State(){

}
State State::Interpolate(State current,State previous,const double alpha){
//current*alpha + previous * ( 1.0 - alpha );
return current;
}
void State::Integrate(State current, double t, const double dt){
}
void State::AddObject(Object object){
storage.push_back(object);
}
void State::RemoveObject(int tag){
//for(int i=0;i<storage.size;i++){
//  if(storage.at(i).getTag==tag){
//storage.erase(storage.begin()+i);
//  }
//}
}
void State::DrawAll(void)
{
  // reset view matrix
  glLoadIdentity();
// move view back a bit
glTranslatef(0, 0, -30);
// apply the current rotation

glRotatef(rotate_z, 0, 0, 1);
rotate_z += 5;
// by repeatedly rotating the view matrix during drawing, the
// squares end up in a circle
int i = 0, squares = 15;
float red = 0, blue = 1;
for (; i < squares; ++i){
  Square square;
Object * squareP=&square;
glRotatef(360.0/squares, 0, 0, 1);
// colors change for each square
red += 1.0/12;
blue -= 1.0/12;
squareP->SetValues(red,0.6,blue);
squareP->Draw();
  }
}
```

The Object header -

```
#ifndef Object_H
#define Object_H

class Object{
int tag;

public:
void SetValues(int,int,int);
void Draw();
int getTag();
};
class Square: public Object{
int red;
int green;
int blue;
void Draw();
void SetValues(int red2,int green2, int blue2);
};
#endif
```

Lastly the State header -

```
#ifndef State_H
#define State_H

#include "Object.h"
#include <vector>
class State{
private:
std::vector<Object> storage;
public:
State();
State Interpolate(State, State, double);
void Integrate(State,double, const double);
void DrawAll();
void AddObject(Object);
void RemoveObject(int);
};
#endif
```

This is the first C++ project I have worked on and have not fully transferred from a Java background.  What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Object` class has no implementation of `SetValues` function. You may want a pure virtual function. Same for `Draw`.

```
class Object {
    virtual void SetValues(int,int,int) = 0;
}
```

Also note that in C++ functions are not virtual by default. You have to use the `virtual` keyword explicitly in the base class.

Also `class Object` seems to be defined at multiple places. Why? Defining it in Object.h would be sufficient.

Also **please indent** your code because it is very hard to read.

Also `std::vector<Object>` will not do what you want! Unline Java, where everything is a reference, in C++ things are stored by value in an `std::vector` and therefore your code is subject to the slicing problem. You want to use at lease a pointer there (`std::vector<Object*>`) but a smart pointer would be even better (`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>`)

Comment: When implementing the above (except the multiple declaration of class Object as I cannot see multiple) I get a single error `Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __cdecl Square::SetValues(int,int,int)" (?SetValues@Square@@EEAAXHHH@Z) C:\Users\Asher\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Procedural Terrain\Procedural Terrain\State.obj Procedural Terrain`

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to move the SetValues and everything is now fine and dandy! I appreciate the help very much!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is marked as `virtual`, and I can't see any implementation for Object::Draw() or Object::SetValues().

In C++ to allow a subclass to override a function in the base class, it needs to be marked as `virtual` (in Java everything is always "virtual").

You can have "abstract" methods (like Java) by saying

```
class Object {
    public:
        virtual void SetValues(int,int,int) = 0;
```

Comment: When I change those functions into abstract ones, I get the error saying I can't refer to that abstract class directly. However, I need to be able to store Square and multiple other entities inside a vector with the same basic functions. By not refering to Object directly I do not know what to do.

Comment: By following your help and Csq's help, I was able to figure out the virtual keyword and using pointers to reference the class. Thank you very much!